# ValidationCalloutExtender and Requiredfildvalidater not working

Tags: asp.net

I have added ValidatorCalloutExtender and Requerfield validater and evrything was working well. but after i have restarted my pc,its no longer showing the validations message box it only putcurse to the tewxtbox to shows that is validating but now showing at...

What seems to be the broblem?

TEXBOX

Requerfield validater and ValidatorCalloutExtender

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicyStatus" runat="server" Width="250px" HighlightCssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" BorderColor="#669999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server" HighlightCssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/ico_error.png" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2" Enabled="true"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

Comment: `Requerfield`? Your title suggests that you know the correct spelling, please be more careful.

Comment: sorry for my wrong spelling..

Answer (score 0):

try this one, You Control should like:

asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1"   runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidatorID" Width="350px" /asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>